# Pass parameter form MVC to Stimulsoft report

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, stimulsoft

The View code is as follows:

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc;
@using Stimulsoft.Report;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListPouyaProject";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_mainView.cshtml";
}

<section class="content">
    <!-- Default box -->
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            Start Date: <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1" onclick="PersianDatePicker.Show(this, '1392/03/22');" />
           End Date : <input type="text" id="date2" name="date2" onclick="PersianDatePicker.Show(this, '1397/03/22');" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(new StiMvcViewerOptions()
                {
                    Actions =
                    {
                        GetReport = "Report4_ListPouyaProject",
                        ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
                    }
                })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The Controller code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Report4_ListPouyaProject()
{
    var report = new StiReport();
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/ListPouyaProject.mrt"));
    return StiMvcViewer.GetReportResult(report);
}
public ActionResult ListPouyaProject()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult ViewerEvent()
{
    return StiMvcViewer.ViewerEventResult();
}
```

I want to pass the `date1` and `date2` variables to the controller from view.

To do this, we need to add the following commands to the contoroller :

```
report.CompiledReport.DataSources["spm_report_4_ListPouyaProject"].Parameters["StartDate"].ParameterValue = DateTime.Parse(date1);


report.CompiledReport.DataSources["spm_report_4_ListPouyaProject"].Parameters["EndDate"].ParameterValue = DateTime.Parse(date2);
```

How to pass the parameters `date1` and `date2` from view to controller?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add the StiMvcViewer component to the view page. Also, you need to pass the StiMvcViewerOptions object to the constructor. The minimum required options are two actions - GetReport and ViewerEvent, they are located in the Actions options group.

```
  @using Stimulsoft.Report.MVC;
    @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(new StiMvcViewerOptions()
        {
            Actions =
            {
                GetReport = "GetReport",
                ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
            }
        })

    <div style="width: 150px;">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Simple List", "Index", new { id = "1" })
                    <br />Report Snapshot
                </div>
```

and in controoller :

```
public ActionResult GetReport(int? id)
    {
        // Create the report object
        StiReport report = new StiReport();
     switch (id)
{
    // Load report snapshot
    case 1:
        // Load report
         // Load report snapshot
               report.LoadDocument(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/SimpleList.mdc"));
                break;
    }
              // Load data from XML file for report template
        if (!report.IsDocument)
        {
            DataSet data = new DataSet("Demo");
            data.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Data/Demo.xml"));

            report.RegData(data);
        }
        return StiMvcViewer.GetReportResult(report);
    }
    public ActionResult ViewerEvent()
    {
        return StiMvcViewer.ViewerEventResult();
    }
```